# Kentico forms disable the data capture and just send the notification

Tags: kentico

Is it possible to disable the data storage and just have the data sent with the notification email? I'm hoping to avoid writing custom code that will just send the form data as an email.

Some of what is being collected is confidential and there are worries about it being stored in the DB. I know, don't ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to store data then you can set the field type to "Field without database representation"  This will allow you to have a "placeholder" for that field and not store any data in the database without writing any code.  This will work for v8 and v9 without issue, I'm not sure about v7.

[image: Field without database representation]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Brenden!

Comment: Doesn't this just prevent that field from being stored?  The submission of the form still creates a record, right?

Comment: Yes @RobM he still wanted to store some of the record that was submitted but not the specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object Events and override the On Before Insert function.  You will have to use that function to not save the data and handle the notification (not sure if the default notification would still fire or not, you might have to do it through code at that point).  you should be able to do with e.Cancel or something like that.

You can read more about these events here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Reference+-+Global+system+events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-BizFormItemEvents and here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Handling+object+events

Comment: Thanks Virgil. I"ll read up and then see if its worth it. May be quicker to just to code out the form and the SMTP sender portion.